# Keep a rolling count of appearances of string in a vector in R

Tags: r

My problem is best addressed with a quick and simple example:

```
my_strings = c("apple", "banana", "carrot", "apple", "apple", "dairy", "banana", "eggplant", "flowers", "flowers", "apple", "banana")

my_repeats = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2)
```

The my_repeats vector can best be understood by going through the my_strings element from start to finish, one element at a time. Since apple, banana, and carrot hadn't yet appeared in the string when first visited, they all are assigned 0. Then apple appears for the 2nd and 3rd times (repeats for 1st and 2nd time), so it gets 1 and 2. Then 0 since dairy hadn't appeared yet, then 1 since banana repeated for the 1st time, etc.

Being able to count the recurrences of strings, and store that data in a vector of the same length, would help a ton with what I'm working on. But I'm not quite sure a quick, vectorized way to do this. Any thoughts appreciated!

EDIT: essentially what i need is a cumulative count function - im checking now if one exists for strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ave` function with `seq_along` can be used for this:

```
as.numeric(ave(my_strings, my_strings, FUN = seq_along)) - 1
##  [1] 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 3 2
```

There's also the `rowid` function from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
rowid(my_strings) - 1
##  [1] 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 3 2
```

Comment: This is too direct and simple - how about `as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "0", make.unique(my_strings)))`  instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution, for strings in a column of a data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(words = c("apple", "banana", "carrot", "apple", "apple", "dairy", 
                            "banana", "eggplant", "flowers", "flowers", "apple", "banana"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(words) %>% 
  mutate(count = sequence(n()) - 1)
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly create a `data.frame`, do you? Can't you just make it part of your pipeline? `data.frame(my_strings) %>% group_by(my_strings) %>% mutate(count = sequence(n())-1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not the easiest way, but if you want to dig into the internals of this you can program it yourself as

```r
mat <- apply(sapply(unique(my_strings), function(x) x == my_strings), 2, cumsum) - 1L
diag(mat[, my_strings])
#>  [1] 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 3 2
```